# How to Inject Window into Angular 2.1.0

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In the earlier RC releases of Angular 2 I was able to inject the window object by adding

`{provide: Window, useValue: window}`

To the providers array.

Since upgrading to the latest stable release of angular 2 (2.1.0) this now throws a console error

> compiler.umd.js:14268Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: (AuthService, UserMessagesService, ?).

The ? in the parameter list is where I am trying to inject the Window object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you don't need to inject the window object, since it's already globally available in browser running JS.

Comment: @rinukkusu When I unit test my components I need to be able to mock out the window object, and when doing so I would prefer using the standard DI that angular 2 provides instead of modifying the window object itself. If it isn't possible to inject the native window, I will probably end up creating a wrapper over it. I was just hoping that I didn't have to as the Window injection was working in a prior version.

Comment: You can use this with Angular4 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-window-token

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try with:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
   { provide: "windowObject", useValue: window}
  ]
})

export class HomeModule {}
```

in your component:

```
constructor(@Inject("windowObject") window: Window})
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks, Any reason why they removed the ability to Inject the Window type directly?

Comment: it seem that window object is not portable ... https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12694#issuecomment-258348560

Answer (score 18):

In order for it to work with AOT you need to do useFactory instead of useValue:

```
export function windowFactory() {
  return window;
}
```

module:

```
providers: [
   { provide: 'window', useFactory: windowFactory }
]
```

component:

```
constructor(@Inject('window') window: Window})
```