# Access global variable in Angular (`LC_API`)

Tags: angular, livechat

I have an Angular 6 app with [Live Chat for Angular](https://github.com/livechat/angular-livechat) installed.

I'm trying to use the [Live Chat Javascript API library](https://developers.livechatinc.com/docs/js-api/#using-chat-window-api) to hide the default floating button.

If I run `LC_API.hide_chat_window();` in the browser developer console, it works.

However, if I add that code to the Angular component .ts file, it does not work (Because it does have access to the global variable `LC_API`).

How can I get access to that global variable?

Comment: Define does not work. Transpile error or a run time error? Please also provide the error message.

Comment: The error is simply that `LC_API` is undefined.

Comment: You could inject `window` into your component and then access the variable on there as traditionally in JS that is where global variables reside. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222547/1260204

Comment: Nevermind. I figured the other thing out. Post as an answer so I can mark as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject window into your component and then access the variable on there as traditionally in JS that is where global variables reside. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222547/1260204

You can shape the expected interface in the constructor for type safety.

```
constructor(@Inject("windowObject") private window: {LC_API:any})
```