# Angular Force Reload

Tags: angular, import, ngrx, reload, ngrx-effects

i am trying to do a forced reload after a logout.

I am using NGRX and after a logout dispatch action, i am trying to:

```
        this.router.navigated = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

Because i need to reload a imported file at my Theme Component.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    import('../../assets/js/scripts.bundle.js');
  }
```

If I logout and try to login again, i am losing this JS, so a full reload can help me.

Any suggestions?

I cant put this .js on angular.json because i cant use him at a few pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with a href at logout button.
Isnt the best solution i guess, but works.

Answer (score 0):

After a logout, try doing `window.location.reload();`.

And to be future proof where you want to do server side rendering, you should create the window like in the following post: [How to Inject Window into Angular 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222084/how-to-inject-window-into-angular-2-1-0).

But if you know you won't be doing server side rendering, just using window directly in your component should be fine.